# Android autocompletetextview with approximate string matching

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, string-search

I am developing an application which has about 8000 names of the cities of India. And when the user types in i use auto complete to help the user to do the job. But some city names have spelling which is hard to guess for people from other states. So we need a approximate string matching for auto complete rather than exact matching which comes by default.

For example there are names like

- Thirumayilai
- Thirunettur
- Thiruthuraiyur
- Thiruvarur

And also

- Tirunelveli
- Tirumangalam

If a user search for the city 'Tirunelveli' But types in text box as 'Thirunel' the autocompletetextview doens't show the name and it does a exact string match.

What should i do to get approximate matching strings in the auto complete drop down list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of search and experiments i found the solution myself..

To do custom string matching we need a custom array adapter which we need to [extend ArrayAdapter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379261/extending-arrayadapter-in-android) and write our own string matching algorithm.

We need to overide `getFilter` method of ArrayAdapter class for this functionality and add `getItem` and `getCount` methods to our custom adapter class.

Comment: I'd much more interested in the technique you used for performing approximate string matching.

Answer (score 6):

You need to Create a Custom ArrayAdapter with a Custom Filter (which filter's based on [Lexographic Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) being less than a certain threshold (say 3)) which you need return in the `getFilter()` method of you Adapter.